# ngFor throw error on passing an array

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the object Categories(id, name), I get like this on Angular:

```
this.categories = new Array<Category>();

this.http
    .get(ApiConfig.API_URL + 'getCategories')
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => this.categories = response.json())
    .catch(_ => console.log("error getting categories"));
```

The object Categories.ts:

```
export class Category
{
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public name: string)
    { }
}
```

And I am trying to put them as options on autocomplete field like this:

```
<div>
  <md-form-field>
    <input type="text" mdInput [mdAutocomplete]="auto">
  </md-form-field>
  <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let category of categories">
      {{ category.name }}
    </md-option>
  </md-autocomplete>
</div>
```

But I get the following error

> Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

I tried with

```
<md-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.id" [label]="category.name">
```

But it still throwing the same error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you change `.then(response => this.categories = response.json())` to `.then(response => { this.categories = response.json(); console.log(%O, this.categories); })` and show us the output?

Comment: I am not sure if it's related to your issue, but your class properties are not correctly declared. put         public id: string,
        public name: string outside of the constructor.

Comment: @Vega, there is nothing wrong with that declaration. That is absolutely correct code. Imagine injecting a service in constructor, but you are able to use that throughout the class. This is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the json you commented, you need to iterate over `categories.result`. Change your `*ngFor` to following:

```
  <md-option *ngFor="let category of categories.result">
      {{ category.name }}
  </md-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a console.log(this.categories) where you are getting your response and then see what's being assigned to categories. I am sure that you parsing it in wrong way.

Comment: You should write that as a comment or support your answer with an example.

Comment: Not enough rep for a comment I think

Comment: I got this: {"result":[{"id":1,"name":"Football"},{"id":2,"name":"Basketball"},{"id":3,"name":"Rugby"}],"id":175,"exception":null,"status":5,"isCanceled":false,"isCompleted":true,"creationOptions":0,"asyncState":null,"isFaulted":false}

Comment: Greate !! 
you then have to use this.categories.result to access your data instead of this.categories...